# how to sort data in the file from file System read method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to sort the data obtained from  read filesystem method
in javascript

```js
fs.readFile('node1.txt',function(err,data){
   if(err){
      return console.log(err)    
   }

   data.toString().toLocaleUpperCase.sort(function (first, second){
      if(first<second){
         return -1
      } else if(first>second) {
         return 1
      } else {
         return 0
      }
   })
}
```

**Error**: `TypeError: sort is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what your code is trying to do here with the line `data.toString().toLocaleUpperCase.sort` is :

Taking the data, transforming it into a string with the `toString()` method and the sorting the string.

The problem here is that you're trying to sort a string and in Javascript, `String` has not `sort` method.

What you should do is transforming your string into an array with the `split` method [(documentation here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

For example if you want to sort the file into words :

```js
data.toString().split(' ').sort(function (first, second){
   if(first.toLocaleUpperCase() < second.toLocaleUpperCase()){
      return -1
   } else if(first.toLocaleUpperCase() > second.toLocaleUpperCase()){
      return 1
   } else{
      return 0
   }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`toLocalUpperCase()` is a function not a property.

Try `data.toString().toLocaleUpperCase().sort(...)`

Note the extra brackets